# Django Channels - chat

Tags: django, message, django-channels

I want to create an app to allow users on my site to message each other in real time. Channels seem to be the logical choice however, all the resources I'm finding online is for making more of a chat room. Where can I find tutorials or recourses on making a single peer-to-peer chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concur on **channels** being the go to method. As  Channels allows Django to support WebSockets in a way that’s very similar to traditional HTTP views. Channels also allow for background tasks that run on the same servers as the rest of Django. HTTP requests continue to behave the same as before, but also get routed over channels

Also, have a look [this](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat), [chat tut](https://danidee10.github.io/2018/01/01/realtime-django-1.html) & [gearheart chat](https://gearheart.io/blog/creating-a-chat-with-django-channels/)